# Running Android Emulator sets audio volume to 100%

Tags: audio, cinnamon, android

I working with Android Studio now, and when I test my app on real device connected to PC, everything is OK. But if I run Android Emulator (Pixel 2, level 29 API), sound volume of my PC is being set to maximum somewhy, which can deliver little problems if u work at Night.

I tried either to download 30th API level or use Nexus emulator instead of Pixel one, but nothing of that helps.

My application doesnt deal with audio for now, and error occurs even before any activity starts.
My DE is Cinnamon, OS is Void-linux if it does matter. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hmmm… I can remember I had these problems a long time ago when pulseaudios "feature" of [flat-volumes](https://200ok.ch/posts/2019-05-20_disable_flatvolume_for_pulseaudio.html) have been default. But since PA 13.0 this seems to be changed. PA13 is in void-linux since Sept 2019. Are you sure you don't have this enabled (by accident or because of an old default written to the config)

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps that solved that problem for me. It works only if you don't need audio in VM.

- Open AVD manager (on the right in android studio click on name of your device and then AVD manager)
- Click on arrow in actions column
- Show on disk
- Open config.ini
- add following 2 lines:

  hw.audioInput=no
  hw.audioOutput=no
- save
- hard reboot device (I've also wiped data)